# Netty 4 ChannelGroup.find(ChannelId id) but no find(String/Integer id)

Tags: netty

When I upgrade from Netty 3 to Netty 4,I found the ChannelGroup has find(Integer id) API to get the Channel in Netty3 while it changes to find(ChannelId id) in Netty 4.When I find an id from databse, I can't find any API to get the Channel by id with String/Integer Type param in Netty 4.Also can't use the String/Integer id to find the ChannelId.
Thanks in advance!

I had searched for a long time on net. Any ideas?Netty 4 uses ConcurrentMap to maintain the channel in channelGroup.If it is unsolvable, Now I want to maintain one by myself.

Netty3

```
public interface ChannelGroup extends Set<Channel>, Comparable<ChannelGroup> {
    Channel find(Integer var1);
    // ...
}
```

Netty4

```
public interface ChannelGroup extends Set<Channel>, Comparable<ChannelGroup> {
    Channel find(ChannelId var1);
    // ...
}
```

I expect it has such API like ChannelGroup.find(String/Integer id) to get the Channel in Netty 4 or use the id to get the ChannelId.

Answer (score 0):

In Netty 4.x the Channel id is not just and integer to reduce the risk of collisions. You `ChannelId` is `Serializable` so you can recreate it from a `byte[]` tho.